# PowerShell - how to remove .vs folder

Tags: powershell

We use a powershell script to clean a project when we need to manually publish it.

This works fine but I need to extend it for de .vs folders

I tried this:

```
Get-Childitem $map -recurse -include .vs | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Remove-Item -force -Recurse
```

But it is'n doing anything

Also tried this:

```
Get-Childitem $map -recurse -include ".vs" | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Remove-Item -force -Recurse
```

But again no result.

Any ideas on how to remove folders like this one in powershell script?

Comment: `Remove-Item -Path "$map/.vs" -Recurse -Force`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "publish", but if you're referring to pushing it to git, just put your `.vs/` folder in the `.gitignore`

Comment: wouldnt' a simple `Get-ChildItem -Path $map -Directory -recurse -filter '*.vs' | Remove-Item ` be enough?

Comment: @sirtao You still need a `-Recurse` on `Remove-Item` if it has contents.  I can't remember if Visual Studio is marking any of those contents as read-only in the filesystem, so `-Force` is added to ignore errors that would crop up from that.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley Thats's what I get for being lazy and not bothering with common\implied parameters! Thanks for pointing them out. One never know when somebody who does NOT know they are common\implied would read this

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley: It only removed the .vs folder in the root folder. But I need it to remove it from every subfolder as well. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is from Maximilian Burszley

```
Remove-Item -Path "$map/.vs" -Recurse -Force
```

thank you!

update:

I managed to make it remove the folders in all subfolders as well:

```
Get-Childitem $map -recurse -include ".vs" -force | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Remove-Item -force -Recurse
```

All I needed extra was the **-force** in the Get-Childitem part.

Comment: Nice, but note that you can use `-Directory` with `Get-ChildItem`, which obviates the need for `Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer}`